# SugarCRM Rest API (v10) Call to related records from multiple links at a time

Tags: api, sugarcrm

I would like to retrieve meeting, call, email related to contact via single api call.
As per api documentation one need to do following api call.

http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.7/Integration/Web_Services/v10/Endpoints/collectioncollection_name_GET/

GET /:module/:record/collection/:collection_name

What should be value of **:collection_name** ?

For example :

GET /Contacts/:record/collection/:**what_should_be_value_of_collection_name**

GET /Leads/:record/collection/:**what_should_be_value_of_collection_name**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These are defined in the module's vardefs. Looking at Sugar 7.6 and 7.7 versions, these are only setup for Calls and Meetings by default.

In Calls and Meetings the only collection available is `invitees`, which is a collection of Contacts, Leads and User records.

Valid calls with the `:collection_name` parameter would be:

```
GET /Calls/:record/collection/invitees    
GET /Meetings/:record/collection/invitees
```

To fetch a collection of related modules for Contacts and Leads you will need to create custom vardefs for these modules.

Look for the `invitees` array in **modules/Calls/vardefs.php** for an example on how that is defined.

Comment: How to make a separate filter for calls, meetings and emails into collection API?
I have used below code but did not work.
$filter_arguments = array(
                    "filter" => array(
                        array(
                            'date_start' => '2016-06-08',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'date_sent' => '2016-06-08',
                        ),
                    ),
                );

Comment: I got below error.
[errors] => stdClass Object(
            [calls] => stdClass Object(
                    [error] => invalid_parameter
                    [error_message] => Unknown field date_sent)
            [meetings] => stdClass Object(
                    [error] => invalid_parameter
                    [error_message] => Unknown field date_sent)
            [emails] => stdClass Object (
                    [code] => 422
                    [error] => invalid_parameter
                    [error_message] => Unknown field date_start))

Comment: You need to create a new question asking about how to add a custom filter on a collection. Include the code from these comments to outline the issue you're having